# How to find an element with Enzyme that's returned by a function from another component's children prop

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme

I'm writing unit tests for the following container component with Jest and Enzyme:

```jsx
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import { Tab } from 'Desktop/components/common'
import { ROUTES } from 'Desktop/constants'

export default class TabContainer extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    routeExact: false,
  }
  static propTypes = {
    routeExact: PropTypes.bool,
    routePath: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(ROUTES)).isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    const { routeExact, routePath, ...props } = this.props

    return (
      <Route exact={routeExact} path={routePath} children={({ match }) => (
        <Tab {...props} active={match ? true : false} route={routePath} />
      )} />
    )
  }
}
```

I'm writing tests for the `Tab`, but the issue is that I'm having trouble traversing the DOM with Enzyme to fetch it. In an ordinary component you'd be able to fetch it using `.find('Tab')`.

In this case, though, it doesn't work because the `Route`'s `children` prop is a function that returns a component (instead of just a component). This means that Enzyme can't traverse the DOM tree to find the `Tab`.

How can I fetch the `Tab` in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that I was using [Enzyme's shallow rendering API](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html). Using `.find('Tab')` works fine with the [full rendering API](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html), as it evaluates the `Route`'s `children` prop (so the `Tab` can be located).